# Magento Attribute set Problem

Tags: magento-1.9

I Have a 2 Attribute set let assume

Toys and Baby care

Toys Menu i have an attribute **gendernew**

Baby Care Menu i Have an attribute **babycare_gender**

Toys Menu have Different Menu and Baby care have different menu

My Problem is I click Baby care Menu it shows gendernew and babycare_gender also even Baby care attribute set dosen't have gendernew attribute

How i will fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check that category, that will have the products of both attribute sets so it rendering both attributes.
Update the category products and reindex.

Comment: I have only 1 product, attribute set is Baby care it does not have gendernew attribute but it showing frontend

Comment: Have you reindexed ?

Comment: yes i reindex multiple time

Comment: Check the attribute set once again, if only one product is listed in category then that product must have the listed attributes.

Comment: Ok i will check